# Website plagiarizing math.stackexchange material

Tags: discussion, scraper-sites

I just discovered that the question [Representing a binary number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98700/representing-a-binary-number) has been copied without citation to http://www.qandasystem.info/math/representing-a-binary-number/.

I suspect that the website "Q&A System" has plagiarized other stackexchange material.  I recommend that the moderators look into this.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Qiaochu and Zev.  I apologize for not searching similar questions before posting my own.  I wanted to vote to close as "no longer relevant" but that option isn't available.  Also, I couldn't vote it as an "exact duplicate" as the question it duplicates is not in Mathematics Meta.

Comment: No need to apologize, or close the question! I appreciate any user taking an active interest in helping out the site, and I wouldn't expect people to search on meta.SO - it's a separate site, and much more crowded with quetsions at that.

Comment: I wonder how many questions posted without citation in math.se are from other sources?  And how many answers?  If *we* have plagiarized material, can we complain about them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[This site has recently been reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131884/161783) to the SE team. See also [this meta.SO post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers).

Comment: An update on the info given in the first link; [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do)

Answer (score 11):

Similar things have been happening to StackOverflow and probably some of the other sites for awhile now (I first became aware of this a year ago). And of course it has been happening to Wikipedia for ages... suffice to say that the SE team is very much aware that this kind of thing happens (although maybe not to this particular site).